# cannot get dockerfile from dockerhub to work on huggingface spaces

Tags: python, node.js, docker, huggingface

the image runs perfectly when i run it in a container but then but it do not work when pushed to the hub and used in my hugging face spaces
I cannot get my docker image that is in the hub to work inside my hugging face space this is the dockerfile inside the space
image pushed to the hub[image in the hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCqmm.png)

```
# Use the circulartextapp/speedinga:1.0 image from the Docker Hub as the base image
FROM circulartextapp/speedtime:latest

# User Setup (if needed)
RUN useradd -m -u 1001 user

# Set environment variables
ENV HOME=/home/user \
    PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set the working directory in the container to the application directory
WORKDIR /code

# Copy Python requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Copy your application files into the container
COPY . /code


# Expose any ports your application might use (if applicable)
EXPOSE 7860

# Specify the command to run your Node.js application
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

this is the error [error image on Hf spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7GU.png) and this is the docker image i pushed to the hub # Use the base Docker image
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.11-nodejs20

```
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system packages including ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ffmpeg && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy Python requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Copy Node.js application files
COPY package*.json .

# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install Node.js dependencies, including Express
RUN npm install express
# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 7860

# Set the default command to start the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

i tried this witout using express and it still did not work i tried to run express inside the dockerfile inside the space but then the whole space just timesout after 30 minutes this is the huggingface spaces

i tried putting this inside my original image # Install Node.js dependencies, including Express
RUN npm install express and also the requirements and also the spaces image

Comment: I see step `COPY . .`, you copy all file in your project. In your local project, it have folder `node-modules`?. If it have, try to add ignore into .dockerignore because you copy and over folder node-modules in the image

Comment: it still timeout on hugging face spaces even after adding this to the original build image .dockerignore # Node.js dependencies
node_modules

# Docker-related files
Dockerfile
.dockerignore

# Build artifacts
*.pyc
*.swp
*.log
*.tmp
__pycache__